# Почему setInterval не работает?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Почему не выводится имя? Ведь стрелочная функция сохраняет контекст вызова, по идее все должно работать, но это не так. Если заменить `this.name` на `obj.name`, то все работает как надо, из этого сделал вывод, что что-то не так с контекстом, поправьте, если что-то не так понял.

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Coal',
  float: () => {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(this.name);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
obj.float();
```

Comment: Я **не уверен**, но логика мне подсказывает что this ссылается на "объект" в котором находится, в вашем примере это инлайн функция....

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что `this` в стрелочной функции ссылается не на объект, в котором эта функция расположена в коде, а на текущий `this` того кода, который эту стрелочную функцию создаёт. Если в код добавить вывод `this`, то будет видно, что это либо глобальный объект:

```js
console.log(this + ""); // этот this будет и у стрелочной функции

const obj = {
  name: 'Coal',
  float: () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.name);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

obj.float();
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы внутри метода `float` `this` ссылался на `obj`, этот метод должен быть традиционной функцией.

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Coal',
  float: function() {
    console.log("float: ", this.name);
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log("setInterval: ", this.name);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
obj.float();
```

В Вашем коде стрелочная функция, присвоенная `float`, сохраняет контекст, в котором создается `obj`, но это не `obj` с  `name: 'Coal'`.